# xlRange.Cells.Value2 Returns Null Even Though Excel Sheet Cell Has Content

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, excel-interop

Basically in my program I am attempting to read an excel file using xlRange.Cells[I,j].Value2. This works for practically all the data I have in the excel file, however, there are a few datapoints where Value2 returns as null, even though the cell in the excel file is filled with content. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: At least yesterday. Now it won't read any of the datapoints in my file. I didn't change anything in that function

Comment: Need some examples of the spreadsheet and which cells return null.